# How to encapsulate complex xml data in single top level object Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I will try to be as clear as I can. This question was inspired from a previously asked question from years ago.

I'd like to to encapsulate xml data into a single Root element object.

So for the following **XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FosterHome>
    <Orphanage>Happy Days Daycare</Orphanage>
    <Location>Apple Street</Location>
    <Families>
        <Family>
            <ParentID>Adams</ParentID>
            <ChildList>
                <ChildID>Child1</ChildID>
                <ChildID>Child2</ChildID>
            </ChildList>
        </Family>
        <Family>
            <ParentID>Adams</ParentID>
            <ChildList>
                <ChildID>Child3</ChildID>
                <ChildID>Child4</ChildID>
            </ChildList>
        </Family>
    </Families>
    <RemainingChildList>
        <ChildID>Child5</ChildID>
        <ChildID>Child6</ChildID>
    </RemainingChildList>
</FosterHome>
```

I have the following JAXB annotated classes.

**FosterHome.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="FosterHome")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FosterHome {

    @XmlElement(name="Orphanage")
    private String orphanage;

    @XmlElement(name="Location")
    private String location;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Families")
    @XmlElement(name="Family")
    private List<Family> families;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="RemainingChildList")
    @XmlElement(name="ChildID")
    private List<String> remainingChildren;
}
```

**Family.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Family {

    @XmlElement(name="ParentID")
    private String parentID;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ChildList")
    @XmlElement(name="ChildID")
    private List<String> childList;
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
public static FosterHome parseXML(File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FosterHome.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        FosterHome fosterHome = (FosterHome) um.unmarshal(file);

        for(Family family : fosterHome.getFamilies()) {
            for(String childID : family.getChildList()) {
                System.out.println(childID);
                // my question is here
                // How to encapsulate all the data into the fosterHome object
                // such as:
                // FosterHome fh = childID.getChildID(); 
            }
        }
        return fosterHome;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    FosterHome fh = parseXML(new File("./testdata/jaxbtest.xml"));
    sysout(fh); // print out all the data from the xml example from above including the data for ChildID
}
```

So my question is: 
How to get ChildID of the type FosterHome, it looks like ChildID is of the type Family, so if you wanted the fosterHome object to contain the childIDs, this may not work. Do anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Something like FosterHome.Family may not be possible since the classes are decoupled. So when I do a `fosterHome.getChildID()` I will get a childID of type `FosterHome`.

Comment: I am still not clear, what are you asking. as this line `FosterHome fosterHome = (FosterHome) um.unmarshal(file);` stores whole XML data into fosterHome Object.

Comment: @SachinGupta if you look at this line `FosterHome fh = childID.getChildID();` Currently it is not syntactically correct. I want `childID.getChildID();` to return type FosterHome. That is the essence of my question.

Comment: I modified my question to be a little more clear. So like when I do a `fosterHome.getChildID()` I would get a childID